# Email import unused MIMEMultipar() Undefined Name Python Gmail Api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, email, gmail

Hi I am working on a gmail api project to send an email through python. Here is my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import base64
import email
import os

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action']

def create_message_with_attachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.
    file: The path to the file to be attached.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject

  msg = MIMEText(message_text)
  message.attach(msg)

  content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file)

  if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
    content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
  main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
  if main_type == 'text':
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  elif main_type == 'image':
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  elif main_type == 'audio':
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  else:
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
    msg.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
  filename = os.path.basename(file)
  msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
  message.attach(msg)

  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
    print(message['id'])
    return message
    


def main():


    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle','rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials = creds)
    userId = 'me'
    
    sender = 'email1'
    to = 'email2'
    subject = 'Output'
    message_text = 'text'
    file = 'output.txt'
    
    message = create_message_with_attachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file)
    
    send_message(service, userId, message)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue I am having is the ide states that email import is unused and the compiler returns that MIMEMultipart() is not named.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-9648eed3ee22>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/samee/Documents/zoom_auto_join/zoom_auto_join_working/sendData.py', wdir='C:/Users/samee/Documents/zoom_auto_join/zoom_auto_join_working')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/samee/Documents/zoom_auto_join/zoom_auto_join_working/sendData.py", line 105, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/samee/Documents/zoom_auto_join/zoom_auto_join_working/sendData.py", line 96, in main
    message = create_message_with_attachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file)

  File "C:/Users/samee/Documents/zoom_auto_join/zoom_auto_join_working/sendData.py", line 26, in create_message_with_attachment
    message = MIMEMultipart()

NameError: name 'MIMEMultipart' is not defined
```

For context I accidentally named this file email.py.  After doing this I remembered that email is an import and renamed it to sendData.py. I believe this may have caused an issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Thanks too the comments I added

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
```

My new issue is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendData.py", line 108, in <module>
    main()
  File "sendData.py", line 99, in main
    message = create_message_with_attachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file)
  File "sendData.py", line 44, in create_message_with_attachment
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: To start with, give the file a different name, for example `myemail.py`.  `email.py` will clash with the standard library's `email` package.

Comment: Yea I renamed to sendData.py

Comment: `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart`